# Best place to attach onClickListener in recyclerview

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

While i was looking at some tutorials about recycler view.some of them used the viewHolder constructor to attach the onClick listener while some of them used the onBindViewHolder method. which method is the best place to attach the onclicklistener. i'm really confused

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `onBindViewHolder` is called every time when you bind your view with data. So there is not the best place to set click listener. You don't have to set `OnClickListener` many times for the one `View`. So the best solution is to set click listener in `onCreateViewHolder` method. But the important thing is a how do you implement on click listener. If you for example want to get some model from list you can use `getAdapterPosition()` method from `ViewHolder`.

Look at the exmaple

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_magazine_list_item, null);

    final ViewHolder result = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
             YourObject yourobject = yourObjectsList.get(result.getAdapterPosition()));
          }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `getPosition()` is now deprecated.

Comment: @BaselShishani Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In `ViewHolder` is the better place:

```
public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    //views declare here

    public ItemViewHolder(View convertView)
    {
        super(convertView);

        ... ...

        convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       //do something to view here
           //also you can get view position by 'getPosition()' here     

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to use the `onClickListener` inside the `ViewHolder` class of the `Recyclview` like below:-

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{    
        private View YOUR_VIEW;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            YOUR_VIEW = itemView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW);

            YOUR_VIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Position==>> "+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
    }
}
```