# viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() in adapter return -1 position and it caused IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick

i try to implement best practice to handle `onclick` in adapter, but i got problem `IndexOutOfBoundException` when `getAdapterPostition` inside `onCreateViewHolder`, whats wrong with my code?

i already try to check but not solve yet.

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private DataFrontVideo datas;
private Context context;

public VideoAdapter(DataFrontVideo datas, Context context) {
    this.datas = datas;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_video,null);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DataVideo video = datas.getContent().get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()); // ERROR HERE
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("datas",video);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    DataVideo dataVideo = datas.getContent().get(position);
    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
    vh.tvTitle.setText(dataVideo.getJudul());
    vh.tvArtis.setText(dataVideo.getAlias());
    vh.tvPrice.setText((dataVideo.getPrice().equals("0")?"Gratis":dataVideo.getPrice()));
    Glide.with(vh.img.getContext()).load(dataVideo.getThumb_pic()).into(vh.img);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (datas == null)? 0 : datas.getContent().size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView tvTitle,tvArtis,tvPrice;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgVideo);
        tvArtis = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvartis);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    }

}
```

}

it should not return -1

Comment: post your DataFrontVideo and DataVideo class code

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getadapterposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `ViewHolder` you need to apply the `setOnClickListener` and get the item position on click by using the **`getAdapterPosition()`** like below

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView img;
        private TextView tvTitle,tvArtis,tvPrice;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgVideo);
            tvArtis = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvartis);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            YOUR_VIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Position==>> "+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    DataVideo video = datas.getContent().get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()); // ERROR HERE
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("datas",video);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem just because you are registering click listener in your onCreateViewHolder which is wrong you need to register on Click listener in your onBindViewHolder like bellow

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    DataVideo dataVideo = datas.getContent().get(position);
    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
    vh.tvTitle.setText(dataVideo.getJudul());
    vh.tvArtis.setText(dataVideo.getAlias());
    vh.tvPrice.setText((dataVideo.getPrice().equals("0")?"Gratis":dataVideo.getPrice()));
    Glide.with(vh.img.getContext()).load(dataVideo.getThumb_pic()).into(vh.img);
vh.parentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("datas",dataVideo);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: many people says that implement onclick inside onBind is not best practice, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28904678/7201326

Answer (score 0):

Move your click in onBindViewHolder .Here it will work for title click ,if you want all click make viewholder complete layout and implement click listener

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
DataVideo dataVideo = datas.getContent().get(position);
ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)viewHolder;
vh.tvTitle.setText(dataVideo.getJudul());
vh.tvArtis.setText(dataVideo.getAlias());
vh.tvPrice.setText((dataVideo.getPrice().equals("0")?"Gratis":dataVideo.getPrice()));
Glide.with(vh.img.getContext()).load(dataVideo.getThumb_pic()).into(vh.img);
 vh.tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("datas",dataVideo );
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: many people says that implement onclick inside onBind is not best practice, see this stackoverflow.com/a/28904678/7201326

Comment: @Asqa there get position is different on onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder